# F# tail call broken by lack of parentheses

Tags: f#, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization, tail-call

While testing F# tail calls with F# team [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx) I found that *almost the same* code has the same result but *different* IL although only parentheses in the code differ.

Next code is optimized by compiler and I see `br.s IL_0000` in the end of IL and no calls to `sumSoFar`

```
let rec loopAndSum aList sumSoFar = 
    match aList with
    | [] -> sumSoFar
    | x :: xs -> 
        loopAndSum xs (sumSoFar + x)

loopAndSum [ 1..5 ] 0 
|> printfn "sum: %i"
```

But that piece is not optimized by compiler and it has `call bla_bla.loopAndSum` near to the end of IL.

```
let rec loopAndSum aList sumSoFar = 
    match aList with
    | [] -> sumSoFar
    | x :: xs -> 
        loopAndSum xs sumSoFar + x

loopAndSum [ 1..5 ] 0 
|> printfn "sum: %i"
```

These examples differ only with parentheses around `sumSoFar + x`.
You can play with it and look at IL at [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ce1elj).

Does anybody know why parentheses matter?

Comment: Did you actually test to see if they did the same thing.  The second version will always have `sumSoFar` set to 0.

Comment: @JohnPalmer, both versions print `sum: 15` locally in LinqPad and in the fiddle.

Comment: if you print `sumSoFar` each time you will get different results.

Comment: @JohnPalmer, I found that not. Compose example at fiddle, please.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4B40wQ

Comment: @JohnPalmer, yeah, I found it :) `sumSoFar` is extra parameter here. It can be removed and replaced w/ zero in `match`. It's a more trickier example than I thought. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function application has higher precedence than any operator. So without the parentheses, it is equivalent to:

```
(loopAndSum xs sumSoFar) + x
```

Therefore it is not a tail call: the addition is performed after the recursive call. It is just by chance that the result value is correct.

Comment: thank you for clarification. Could you point at spec where it's described?

Comment: At the bottom of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) there is an operator precedence table, function application is near the bottom between `**` and pattern matching.